# Error Division by zero

Tags: php

У меня появилась эта ошибка когда я перенес файл на хостинг и указал путь к директории. Подскажите что я сделал не так, вот ошибка

`Warning: Division by zero in /home/a7422059/public_html/includes/initialize.php on line 5`

а вот код

```
 define(«SITE_ROOT»,«/home/a7422059/public_html»);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
define(«SITE_ROOT»,«/home/a7422059/public_html»);
```

Поправьте на:

```
define("SITE_ROOT","/home/a7422059/public_html");
```

Comment: Да и правда так, спасибо за совет